# Title and path for periodic articles/analysis

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, title

Let say I have a weekly analysis of the market. This analysis only useful for that week. Although the content is different every week, the title and concept is the same.

In order to have a better SEO which one is a better solution:

1. Add the time stamp to the title and URL of each file.
2. Choose a fix URL and title for this page and update the content every week. (Archive the older ones)
3. Or what?

Also, I would be happy to know some SEO tips on this type of contents (periodically, with the same nature, but different content).

Note, assume that the content is a bunch of charts, and we cannot select a unique title for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.) Follow the lead of other chart-based analysis sites like Netcraft's [Web Server Survey](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/):

List the updated charts on top with a few previous weeks below at a main URL (like the one above), and archive the rest as separate URLs with dates in the title so they're unique.

That way you'll be updating the content at the main URL (search engines tend to like fresh content) instead of completely changing all of the content there, which may cause it to fluctuate in your SERP.

This will also expand your site with URLs and content that can be indexed and internally linked/navigated from, which can signal relevance and pass authority to the main URL, as covered [here](http://www.seomark.co.uk/seo-for-internal-links/#ixzz2qGF128Az).

Comment: In Netcraft's example, each page has its own url which has a unique name using the date. Technically, what you have mentioned is my first solution + an index page that has an abstract of the articles. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's more of a combination of 1 & 2, while including a few weeks of previous charts/content in the main URL like in the Netcraft example.